# Sorting big numbers in R

Tags: r

Data:

> m2 (sample - not the full data)

```
      a           b                   c
4   AGO    114,147  Lower middle income
8   ARM      9,951  Lower middle income
24  BLZ      1,493  Lower middle income
26  BOL     27,035  Lower middle income
30  BTN      1,780  Lower middle income
37  CHN  8,227,103  Lower middle income
38  CIV     24,680  Lower middle income
39  CMR     25,322  Lower middle income
40  COG     13,678  Lower middle income
43  CPV      1,827  Lower middle income
```

when i use "order", I get the below:

> m2[order(m2$b),]

```
   a           b                   c
50  DJI             Lower middle income
199 TMP      1,293  Lower middle income
24  BLZ      1,493  Lower middle income
30  BTN      1,780  Lower middle income
43  CPV      1,827  Lower middle income
91  IND  1,841,710  Lower middle income
140 MNG     10,271  Lower middle income
151 NIC     10,507  Lower middle income
4   AGO    114,147  Lower middle income
40  COG     13,678  Lower middle income
176 SEN     14,046  Lower middle income
162 PNG     15,654  Lower middle income
71  GEO     15,747  Lower middle income
215 VNM    155,820  Lower middle income
105 KIR        175  Lower middle income
207 UKR    176,309  Lower middle income
```

when i use arrange, i get hte below:

> arrange(m2,desc(m2$b))

```
    a           b                   c
1  WBG          .. Lower middle income
2  MAR     95,982  Lower middle income
3  ARM      9,951  Lower middle income
4  IDN    878,043  Lower middle income
5  ECU     84,040  Lower middle income
6  CHN  8,227,103  Lower middle income
7  VUT        787  Lower middle income
8  SYR     73,672  Lower middle income
9  MDA      7,253  Lower middle income
10 WSM        684  Lower middle income
```

The problem appears to be that it is sorting every digit (nos starting with 9 comes first if i sort desc) in the "b" column in asc/desc order. 
I want the descending order of "b" column.
I am new to R. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like your m2$b column might be stored as a string.  Can you run `str(m2)` and check the column's datatype?  If it's numeric, can you post the `str` results

Comment: it says factor:                                          'data.frame': 56 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 234 levels "ABW","ADO","AFG",..: 4 8 24 26 30 37 38 39 40 43 ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 205 levels ""," 1,008 "," 1,129 ",..: 24 186 10 94 13 178 82 85 31 15 ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 6 levels "","High income: nonOECD",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...

Comment: The issue is the comma's, no? You can replace the commas perhaps and then make them numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the m2$b column is currently stored as a factor.  To change a factor into a number you normally just need to convert the factor levels to numbers

```
as.numeric(levels(m2$b))
```

However, as you have commas, you will need to replace these using gsub first

```
gsub(",","",levels(m2$b))
```

Putting this together produces code like:

```
# First two lines to build example
m2   <-  data.frame(a=1)
m2$b <-  as.factor("114,147"  )
m2$b <-  as.numeric(gsub(",","",levels(m2$b)))
m2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that m2 is a matrix and matrices in R can store data of only one class so numbers on column "b" could be converted on-the-fly to string. Check manually what class m2 is:

```
class(m2)
```

If it is matrix then try to read data again but load it into data.frame. You can also convert matrix into data.frame or try to convert chosen column to numeric:

```
m2[order(as.numeric(m2$b)),]
```